# How do I make this PHP code a loop or more dynamic?

Tags: php, wordpress, optimization, loops

The [sample] code below seems like it could be better in a loop or something to make it more dynamic. The only thing that changes is the _xx and _xxyy in the field/variable name. How can I improve this so I don't have to write 20 if statements?:

```
    <?php if (get_custom_field('itinerary_title_02')):?>
    <div id="itinerary_entry">
        <h2><?php print_custom_field('itinerary_title_02'); ?></h2>
        <p><?php print_custom_field('itinerary_content_02'); ?></p>
        <p class="accommodation_name"><?php print_custom_field('itinerary_acc_nme_02'); ?></p>
        <p class="accommodation_desc"><?php print_custom_field('itinerary_acc_dsc_02'); ?></p>
        <?php if (get_custom_field('itinerary_photo_0201')):?>
        <div><img src="<?php print_custom_field('itinerary_photo_0201'); ?>"></div>
        <?php endif;?>
    </div>
    <?php endif;?>

    <?php if (get_custom_field('itinerary_title_03')):?>
    <div id="itinerary_entry">
        <h2><?php print_custom_field('itinerary_title_03'); ?></h2>
        <p><?php print_custom_field('itinerary_content_03'); ?></p>
        <p class="accommodation_name"><?php print_custom_field('itinerary_acc_nme_03'); ?></p>
        <p class="accommodation_desc"><?php print_custom_field('itinerary_acc_dsc_03'); ?></p>
        <?php if (get_custom_field('itinerary_photo_0301')):?>
        <div><img src="<?php print_custom_field('itinerary_photo_0301'); ?>"></div>
        <?php endif;?>
    </div>
    <?php endif;?>

    <?php if (get_custom_field('itinerary_title_04')):?>
    <div id="itinerary_entry">
        <h2><?php print_custom_field('itinerary_title_04'); ?></h2>
        <p><?php print_custom_field('itinerary_content_04'); ?></p>
        <p class="accommodation_name"><?php print_custom_field('itinerary_acc_nme_04'); ?></p>
        <p class="accommodation_desc"><?php print_custom_field('itinerary_acc_dsc_04'); ?></p>
        <?php if (get_custom_field('itinerary_photo_0401')):?>
        <div><img src="<?php print_custom_field('itinerary_photo_0401'); ?>"></div>
        <?php endif;?>
    </div>
    <?php endif;?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wordpress code makes me a sad. Just sayin'.

Comment: use a foreach statement on the get_custom_field, where is it coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
for($i=2 ; $i<5 ; $i++ ){
    $titleNum = sprintf("%02d", $i);
    if (get_custom_field('itinerary_title_'.$titleNum)) {
?>
     <div id="itinerary_entry">
         <h2><?php print_custom_field('itinerary_title_'.$titleNum); ?></h2>
         <p><?php print_custom_field('itinerary_content_'.$titleNum); ?></p>
         <p class="accommodation_name"><?php print_custom_field('itinerary_acc_nme_'.$titleNum); ?></p>
         <p class="accommodation_desc"><?php print_custom_field('itinerary_acc_dsc_'.$titleNum); ?></p>
     <?php if (get_custom_field('itinerary_photo_'.$titleNum.'01')){ ?>
         <div><img src="<?php print_custom_field('itinerary_photo_'.$titleNum.'01'); ?>"></div>
     <?php } ?>
     </div> 
     <?php }
     }
     ?>
```

Comment: so the "$i=2" in the for function represents my starting point? If so, since I'm really starting from the beginning ("02" was just used as an example) I need to replace "$i=2" with "$i=1"?

Comment: one last question: sprintf is simply replacing single digit numbers (i.e., 7) and making them double digit numbers (i.e., 07), right? So when the value of $i is equal to 10 or greater its NOT adding a zero to it (i.e., 010), right? (I googled/researched the sprintf function but it just confused me even more)

Comment: Everything works! I changed $i=2 to $i=1 and the sprintf function does indeed turn single digits to double digits. I did change $i<5 to $i<21 properly get the all 20 possible sets ($i<20 would only return 19). Nonetheless great code! Thanks so very much for your time and contribution!

Comment: @crashintoty nice! the [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) function is used to format the string. You have a lot of options and params. The **0** _Causes printf to use 0 instead of spaces to left-fill a fixed-length field. For example, printf("%2d", 3) results in " 3", while printf("%02d", 3) results in "03"._ And with the number **2** we fixed the lenght to 2 numbers. So when you have 54 there's no need to fill nothing with leading zeros because you already have 2 numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your duplicate code with a [`for`](http://www.php.net/for) loop.

```
<?php
for ( $i = 2; $i <= 4; $i++) { // Modify this range as needed
    $dynamic_value = ($i < 10) ? "0$i" : $i; // Prefix the value with a '0' when necessary

    if ( get_custom_field("itinerary_title_$i")):?> 
        <!-- HTML and PHP goes here. Replace each hard-coded number with '$i' -->
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Loops and and anything with $i++ have anyways been my weakness.